# Multiple Simultaneous gRPC connections to different servers via different interfaces (eth0, wlan0, ppp0)

Tags: c++, linux, protocol-buffers, posix, grpc

We have started using `gRPC C++` for our embedded system project (ARM Processor Cortex-A7) as a client. We have successfully created a sample application which communicates with the server using `protobuf`.

We have a new requirement now. We have to open multiple connections to the different endpoints (or server) via different interfaces (like ethernet, wifi and cellular [using ppp]).

I tried to google but couldn't find any solutions to it. I have tried [gRPC forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/nFm9U4f-J3A) but hasn't received a proper reply to my [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/nFm9U4f-J3A).

I have wondering if `gRPC` has provision to bind to a particular interface or IP. Linux `POSIX` socket provides `SO_BINDTODEVICE` option but I am not sure if gRPC has any application layer method or function to achieve it (can't find it in the documentation).

Or Can we achieve it via some other hack (may be by modifying the routing table?).